# Does Apache Mesos + Marathon support LXD cluster management?

Tags: docker, containers, scale, mesos, lxd

I've seen kubernetes and mesos, which both look awesome. My works has a LXD cluster. I'm wondering if I can manage this cluster using Mesos or Kubernetes for autoscaling. Is this supported?

Comment: Mesosphere announced that they intend to look at supporting LXD: https://insights.ubuntu.com/2016/04/19/open-source-dcos-project-is-announced-by-mesosphere-backed-by-dozens-of-partners-including-canonical-and-microsoft/